# Query thought in sets?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a task that looks like this:

- I have a database with the table - DressSizes
- I have a xml also with dress sizes. This xml is passed as a parameter to the function.
- My goal is to get the data from the table according to the xml which is
  passed.

OUTPUT:

1. if my table contains sizes which are present in xml, I should select the smallest common size.
2. if my table doesn't contain sizes which are present in xml, i should select the smallest size from the table.
3. if i have passed null to the function 2nd must happen.

I already have a working query, that looks like this:

```
ALTER  function [dbo].[DressAvialableSizez]
(
    @DressID int,
    @ListXml xml = NULL
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN
(
    WITH CTE_SizeFilter as
    (
        SELECT Xmldata.Element.value('.','varchar(5)') AS Sizes, S.SortIndex AS FSort, S.DressID
              FROM @ListXml.nodes('/list/i') AS Xmldata (Element)
              INNER JOIN DressesSizes AS S ON S.DressSize = Xmldata.Element.value('.','varchar(5)')
        WHERE S.DressID = @DressID
    )

    SELECT TOP(1) F.Sizes, F.FSort, S.DressSize, S.SortIndex, S.DressID
    FROM DressesSizes AS S
    LEFT JOIN CTE_SizeFilter AS F ON S.DressSize = F.Sizes
    WHERE S.DressID = @DressID AND S.DressSize = IIF( EXISTS (
                        SELECT F.Sizes
                        FROM DressesSizes AS S
                        INNER JOIN CTE_SizeFilter AS F ON S.DressSize = F.Sizes),
                        F.Sizes,
                        S.DressSize)
    order by F.FSort, S.SortIndex
)
```

PROBLEM:

I showed my code to my supervisor but he/she keeps saying that it can be
simplified and i need to think in sets. I seem to struggle in understaning how to "think in sets" and no
googling didn't help. So what can I do, I'm lost.

Comment: He/She is probably referring to the IIF in the WHERE clause.

Comment: Sample tables, data, and expected output would be helpful.

Comment: Kind of sad that they tell you it can be simplified but totally failed you in helping you learn by demonstrating and explaining why it is a better approach. Just saying "learn to think in sets" is pretty worthless. Thinking in sets means you think about what you need to do to a column, not what you want to do to each row.

Comment: The odd thing is that I can't really see anything that doesn't think in a set in that query. I agree with @squillman that `IIF` should be Boolean logic, however, that doesn't change the query to a from a row-based solution to a set-based solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
WITH CTE_SizeFilter as
(
    SELECT Xmldata.Element.value('.','varchar(5)') AS DressSize
    FROM @ListXml.nodes('/list/i') AS Xmldata (Element)
)

SELECT TOP(1) S.DressSize, S.SortIndex, S.DressID
FROM DressesSizes AS S
LEFT JOIN CTE_SizeFilter AS F ON S.DressSize = F.DressSize
WHERE S.DressID = @DressID
ORDER BY CASE WHEN F.Sizes IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, S.DressSize
```

This simply selects the smallest dress size, but prioritizes those that are present in the XML.

<s>PS. It's not clear to me what you should do with the @DressID parameter.</s>

Later edit: I have used the @DressID parameter, considering the revised question.

Comment: this "ORDER BY" does not work because there are more sizes than 2, also I edited and to show what to o with the @DressID parameter.

Comment: @jamesHeller: The `ORDER BY` should work with any dress size. The 1 and 2 present in the first criteria only specify that the dress sizes that are present in the XML list should be more important than the ones that are not present. If there are multiple dress sizes that match the ones in the XML list, then the smallest one is taken, because there is a second ordering criteria for `S.DressSize`.